# MasterCard/Visa Payment Model implementation in Django-python

Tags: python, django

I am working on an online bidding project in Django and want to implement MasterCard/Visa Payment gateway. Can anyone help me?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: stripe is good ... for US payments .. Paypal is also easily implemented

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple Django applications that you can use for this:

- [Django-Bursur](https://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-bursar) - It's listed as 'nearing' beta release
- [Quix.pay](http://www.micahcarrick.com/django-authorize-net-payments.html) - [The PyPi page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/quix.pay/) - This uses the authorize.net gateway
- [Satchmo](https://bitbucket.org/chris1610/satchmo/wiki/Home) - This is what Django-Bursur was forked from
- [Django-Paypal](https://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal) - It's not Visa/Mastercard, but Paypal does accept credit cards as a form of payment.
- [Django-getpaid](https://github.com/cypreess/django-getpaid) - This is only 2 months old. I don't know how well it works
- [Paython](https://github.com/abunsen/Paython) - Standalone library integrates stripe, authorize.net, samurai & couple more